# Python passing variable to a thread created from another file (script)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have two files:

**threadmodule.py**

```
def main():
    print("This is the thread!")
    while 1:
           *do something to set statistic_flag = True*


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**maincode.py**

```
import threadmodule

statistic_flag = True

t = threading.Thread(target=tbot.main)
t.daemon = True
t.start()


while 1:
    if(statistic_flag == True):
        print "flag was True"
        statistic_flag = False
```

I want to do something like `statistic_flag = True` inside of `main()` in threadmodule.py, so that this will let the maincode to print.

I am newbie in Python, I know how thread works but maybe this isn't the best way to do what I would achieve. Feel free to propose another solution that does what I would do, if it is better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the "queue" module. "main()" can put results in a Queue object (or just a None if there are no results) and the maincode takes it and prints.